# Generating more than one excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I tried this code to create an excel sheet.

```
Set ExcelObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

ExcelObject.visible = True
ExcelObject.WorkBooks.Add       
ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).value = "My first excel"
```

But i want more than one excel to be generated So i tried this code-

```
Set ExcelObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

For x= 1 to 5
ExcelObject(x).visible = True
ExcelObject(x).WorkBooks.Add 'Adds a workbook to an excel object
x=x+1   
ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).value = "My first excel"
```

But it is not working.Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some errors:

1. You missed `Next x`
2. You don't have to increment `x` since you use `For..Next` statement. `Next x` will do that for you.

Working code:

For `VB.NET`:

```
Dim ExcelObject() As Object
ExcelObject = New Object(5) {}
For x = 1 To 5
    ExcelObject(x) = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelObject(x).visible = True
    ExcelObject(x).WorkBooks.Add() 'Adds a workbook to an excel object
    ExcelObject(x).Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).value = "My first excel"
Next x
```

For `VBScript`:

```
Dim ExcelObject(5) 
For x = 1 To 5
    Set ExcelObject(x) = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelObject(x).visible = True
    ExcelObject(x).WorkBooks.Add() 'Adds a workbook to an excel object
    ExcelObject(x).Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).value = "My first excel"
Next
```

Comment: I am exeuting these codes by saving it into notepad with the .vbs extension and double clicking on it.When i am executing vbs file with your code, commmand prompt opens for a second and then closes by itself with no output and neither excels are generated.Same thing was happening when i was trying to execute my code.Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

May want to look into using collections.   In the above example where you're using `ExcelObject(x).visible = True`   ---   You really haven't created 5 `ExcelObjects` yet when you created it.

There are several ways to accomplish this. But playing off what you have when you add a workbook.  You're creating instances of workbooks into your workbooks collection.  So rather then reference it as `ExcelObject(x)`   =>   you'll need to reference the workbooks from the items

`ExcelObject.WorkBooks.item(x)`

Comment: Just to make things clear, can you please modify my code? because i tried what you had suggested me but i think i am missing something..